# Having problem with runing composer update while deploying laravel app on my windows machine

Tags: php, security, ssl, composer-php, certificate

composer update error :

In CurlDownloader.php line 372:

curl error 60 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/p2/laravel/sanctum.json: SSL certificate problem: unable
to get local issuer certificate

composer update
and i was expectint it to update all my dependencies